# What is the type of a lambda expression in Scala

Tags: scala, lambda

Say I had a lambda expression something like:
`val ex = (x:Int) => x + x`
what is the type of this expression/how do I know its type? I've tried using "Any" as the function parameter type that didn't work and if I try to get it's type using the .getClass.getSimpleName function I get an object address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of this expression is a [function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html#functions-that-accept-functions) accepting `Int` and returning `Int`, i.e. `Int => Int` (which is a syntactic sugar for `Function1[Int, Int]`):

```scala
val ex: Int => Int = (x:Int) => x + x
```

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA with Scala plugin you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> [shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea-for-scala.html#QuickPopups) to see the type info:

[image]

Comment: `Int => Int` being a shorter syntax for `Function1[Int, Int]`